# ¿Conteo de registros de dos tablas?

Tags: mysql

Desearia saber que sentencia me permitiria poder obtener el numero total de pacientes (tabla 1) y medicos (tabla 2) en un mismo select.

En caso practico, tengo 9 pacientes y 5 medicos. Deberia poder contar con una misma sentancia, los registros de las dos tablas y obtener un resultado de 14.

He utilizado

```sql
select count(pacnombres) from pacientes union select count(mednombres) from medicos;
```

Pero me arroja 2 filas, la primera con 9 (equivalente a pacientes) y otra con 5 (equivalente a medicos).

Tambien he utilizado

```sql
select count(pacnombres and mednombres) from pacientes, medicos;
```

Pero lo que esta haciendo es multiplicar 9 * 5 y me arroja 45 xD

**Ayuda!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mas sencillo es usar las subconsultas a nivel de columna:

```
select (select count(pacnombres) from pacientes) as pacientes,
       (select count(mednombres) from medicos)   as medicos
```

combinados sería:

```
select (select count(pacnombres) from pacientes) +
       (select count(mednombres) from medicos)   as Total
```

Aclaración, esto es posible, por que cada subconsulta retorna un único valor.

Answer (score 3):

Tu consulta debes de formular de la sgte forma:

```
SELECT COUNT(nombre) FROM (
SELECT pacnombre AS nombre FROM pacientes
UNION ALL
SELECT mednombre AS nombre FROM medicos
) as Cantidad_Personas
```

De esta forma ya deberia de aparecerte correctamente la suma de ambos conteos.

Comment: me resulto un conteo de 90 :/

Comment: ajustaste los nombres de los campos dentro del COUNT() ?

Comment: Claro
```mysql
select (count(pacientes.pacnombres) + count(medicos.mednombres)) as cantidad from pacientes, medicos;
```

Comment: ahi ya lo edite

Comment: No te olvides de marcar la respuesta que te sirvió, como la correcta. Para mantener la salud del foro.

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacerlo de esta manera

```
select pacnombres into #temp
from pacientes 
union all
select mednombres 
from medicos;

select count(*) from #temp
```

al parecer no es optimo pero cumple :)

Comment: Me sale error después del #temp :/

Comment: Creo que quieres hacer como una tabla temporal y entiendo solo que no se crearla, el #temp no funciona. Podrías ser un poco más especifico por favor! :c

Comment: no lei que era mysql :(